# Jenkins build Docker container on remote host with dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm quite new to Jenkins and spent 2 whole days not twisting my head (and google and stackoverflow) around, how to get a docker container built on a remote host (from Jenkins host perspective).
My setup:

- Docker runs on a MacOS machine (aka the "remote host")
- Jenkins runs as docker container on this machine
- Bitbucket Cloud runs at Atlassian
- PyCharm is my development tool - running on the MacOS machine

Everything works fine so far. Now, I want Jenkins to build a docker container (on the "remote host") containing my python demo.

I'm using a dockerfile in my project:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
CMD ["test.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

I'm trying to build a jenkinsfile, I'm expecting to do 2 things

- Pull the repo
- Build the docker image with the help of the dockerfile on the "remote host"

Docker is installed as plugin and configured.
Docker is installed via Jenkins configuration.
Docker remote host is set up in "Cloud" setup in Jenkins - connection works (with the help of socat running as docker container)
Docker Host ist set to the remote host IP and port 2376
I'm using a jenkins pipeline project.

Most promising threat about using remote hosts is of course https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-a-remote-docker-server

But using docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.178.26:2376') (in my case, locally, no credentials because not reachable from outside), I had no luck at all.

Most common error message: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withServer() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [tcp://192.168.178.26:2376]`

If I try to let Jenkins build it inside it's own container with its own docker, it tells me `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/dockerbuild@tmp/durable-6e12255b/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dockerbuild@tmp/durable-6e12255b/script.sh: docker: not found`
Strange, as I thought, docker was installed. But I want to build at remote host anyway.

In my eyes the most promising jenkinsfile is the following - but to be honest, I am totally lost at the moment and really need some help:

```
node {
    checkout scm
    docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.178.26:2376')
    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

    customImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'

    }
```

I appreciate any hint and am greatful for your help.
Best regards
Muhackl

Comment: Welcome to SO.              Do you have docker plugin installed? Also, I don't understand the point creating the line docker.withServer() {} , Why would you need to use a remote host connection, if your goal is to download a repo from whatever node, and build it ?

Comment: This is very close to what I'm also trying to do. Haven't been able to find any help resources so far.